# How to send newline into comint mode?

Tags: comint, scheme

I have Scheme REPL written in NodeJS run inside emacs with `run-scheme` and when I execute Scheme code with <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> I end up with a buffer that looks like this:

```
lips> lips> ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... lips>
```

Is there a way to add a newline at the end of the when calling:

```lisp
(scheme-send-last-sexp)
```

I've tried this after looking at the code from `cmuscheme.el`.

```lisp
(defun scheme-send-last-sexp-fix ()
  "Send the previous sexp to the inferior Scheme process
   and add newline at the end"
  (interactive)
  (scheme-send-last-sexp)
  (comint-send-string (scheme-proc) "\n"))

(define-key scheme-mode-map "\C-x\C-e" #'scheme-send-last-sexp-fix)
```

But it doesn't work. When I evaluate expression I keep getting the prompt for each list in expression. I also tried using `"\r"`

I was testing with GNU Guile interpreter and I got exact same behavior. How can I send a newline after each expression is sent to the Scheme process?

Answer (score 0):

For Scheme in particular sending newline takes no effect but you can set scheme code that is hidden:

```lisp
(defun scheme-send-last-sexp-fix ()
  "Send the previous sexp to the inferior Scheme process
   and add newline at the end"
  (interactive)
  (scheme-send-last-sexp)
  (comint-send-string (scheme-proc) "(newline)\n"))
```

This will properly add a newline in inferior Scheme mode.